# Tested implementation of APriori and FP-growth in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am searching for (hopefully) a library that provides tested implementations of APriori and FP-growth algorithms, in python, to compute itemsets mining.

I searched through SciPy and Scikit-learn but I did not find anything. Could anyone point me to something reliable?

Thanks

Comment: I do not get why this is on hold, while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236314/is-there-a-python-implementation-for-the-smote-algorithm?rq=1 is open. Answers are by default opinionated, each one by his author. I asked here because, as there is not a well known implementation, I do not want to take the first gist I get from Google and use it, since it can be not reliable (and I did find something like this)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is [PyFIM](http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html).

It is not provided by pip, but can be downloaded from the previous link. It is created by the author of [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/widm.1074/abstract;jsessionid=0BFF8FF1599F137F5560541E95141639.f01t02).

Comment: Thanks, I found this implementation https://github.com/asaini/Apriori, but did not work for me. I think my CSV might contain special characters and the program is not robust enought to deal with them, so no rules are found for my case. PyFIM works faster (has a C implementation within) and has no problem with characters. Cool package.